# 14.04 w/ Samsung SE-506CB external BRD cannot read or burn blu ray disks.

Tags: 14.04, blu-ray

The drive mounts, but I cannot, "see" anything on it.  I open MakeMKV and back up greyed out. I cannot run the setup disk either. I am trying to backup to Bluray. CD/DVD will not do.

Output of sudo lshw -C storage -C disk

```
*-storage               
   description: SATA controller
   product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
   resources: irq:46 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4)         
 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32)   
 memory:f7d16000-f7d167ff


*-scsi:0
   physical id: 2
   logical name: scsi0
   capabilities: emulated
 *-disk
      description: ATA Disk
      product: Samsung SSD 840
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sda
      version: EXT0
      serial: S1DBNSAF677356E
      size: 232GiB (250GB)
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000e93fb

*-scsi:1
   physical id: 3
   logical name: scsi1
   capabilities: emulated
 *-cdrom
      description: DVD-RAM writer
      product: DVD+-RW SH-216BB
      vendor: TSSTcorp
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
      logical name: /dev/sr0
      version: D100
      capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
      configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc

*-scsi:2
   physical id: 4
   bus info: usb@1:1.3
   logical name: scsi8
   capabilities: emulated scsi-host
   configuration: driver=usb-storage
 *-cdrom
      description: DVD-RAM writer
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sr1
      logical name: /media/xxxx/TSST-ODD
      capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
      configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
```